# Folder naming: src & dist vs. src & build, dev & dist

Tags: gruntjs, gulp, directory, naming

What is the preferred labelling method for your folders to distinguish between the raw assets and those that have been minified, concatenated etc. using a task runner? I've seen a bunch of combinations, the most popular ones being `src and  dist`, `src and build`, `dev and dist`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's subjective, it can be anything you want.  I will tell you that mine is "src : _build".  All of my dev files are contained within the "src" directory, and everything else copies/builds into the "_build" directory.  But there are no set standards.

You can name your concatenated files... so just reference them in your layout file.  For example I concat all my lib js files into a file named lib.min.js, I used a constructor function in my app.js so there is nothing to concatenate there, it's just one file.

Same for my minified css files... lib.min.css, and app.min.css.

I run htmlmin on the _build directory.

Not exactly sure what the question is here, but I hope this helps.